# Android: Unable to swap activity and close app when clicking button

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have an activity (let us call "ResultActivity") which receives some results from another activity ("AuditTest"), and there will be two buttons for user:

First button: let user to send the above-mentioned results to the server via connecting to a PHP webpage, and then go back to the main menu (so called "MainActivity")

Second button: let user to send the results to the server by `ASyncTask`, then ASyncTask will finish

For going back to the main menu, I have tried to use `Intent`, `setClass`, `startactivity` and `finish`. It could manage to go back to main menu, but this ResultActivity won't finish. Once you press back button on the phone, startActivity will close and that ResultActivity comes out again.

And for quitting the app, I also tried to use simply `finish()` method to achieve this, but still have no luck.

So here is the code for ResultActivity, and I also included comments to briefly illustrate operations in the app

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    TextView result_showResultLbl;
    Button result_retry,result_leaveBtn;
    TextView result_noticeLbl;
    boolean fail = false;
    char PF = ' ';
    final int BUTTON_RETRY=1;
    final int BUTTON_LEAVE=2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
          //Summary: Just initializing all widgets, get back all elements 
          //from previous activity and show result to user. 
          ........
          ........

         //setting up onClickListeners for two buttons (result_retry and 
         result_leavebtn. So the ASyncTask is called SendData.

        result_retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //send result to server
                SendData s = new 
                SendData(PF,FArecord,questionAnswers,BUTTON_RETRY);
                s.execute();
            }
        });

        result_leaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SendData s = new 
                SendData(PF,FArecord,questionAnswers,BUTTON_LEAVE);
                s.execute();

            }
        });
    }

    //ASyncTask class SendData
    private class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, String ,String>
    {
          .......//variables, not mentioned here

          //parameters are data from previous activity and which button that user clicked.
          SendData(..........)
          {
                .........
          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... strings) 
          {
               //doInBackground of SendData will get all data sent from 
               //previous activity, then use HttpURLConnection to send out the data and get back the result.

               ...............//get all data from previous activity
               //send php request
                URL dbServerURL = new URL(URLAddr);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) dbServerURL.openConnection();
                Log.v("ResultActivity","URL = "+URLAddr);//for debug
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

                //concat the information fields and then send out the data

                parameters = ....;// parameters is a concatenated string to carry the data.
                out.write(parameters.getBytes());
                Log.v("ResultActivity","Trying to send parameter: "+parameters);
                out.flush();
                out.close();//finish sending out

                //data request is successful
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                String response = FacilityAuditTest.convertStreamToString(is);
                if (response.contentEquals("Error"))
                {
                    //error occurred
                    Log.v("ResultActivity","Received String: "+response);
                } else
                {
                    //get JSON object if no error
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = json.getInt("success");
                    Log.v("ResultActivity","Success= "+success);
                    Log.v("ResultActivity","Record sent successfully");
                }
                is.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String s)
          {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                if (success == 1)
                {
                        //I use runOnUiThread() to detect which button the user has clicked, then swap activity or close the app.

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (clickedButtonType == BUTTON_RETRY)
                        {
                            //if user clicked retry button before, show a success message and then go back to information entry page
                            Toast.makeText(ResultActivity.this,R.string.result_sendSuccess,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.setClass(ResultActivity.this,AuditorInf.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                        if (clickedButtonType == BUTTON_LEAVE)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(ResultActivity.this,R.string.result_sendSuccess,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//I tried to use android.os.Process.killProcess to kill app, but the app still restart and show this ResultActivity after running killProcess.                             android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(1);
                            //finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
                } else
                {
                        //just show fail to transmit message, but the action is similar to (success == 1)
                }
          }
    }


}
```

As what I have added in the comments of the code, the app won't switch to main menu and close current activity. It also cannot close the app by calling finish. I can give more detail code if you need. Thank you.

Comment: why you are using `runOnUiThread `?  `onPostExecute ` already run on UI thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have put the code in the `runOnUiThread` directly to onPostExecute, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Does `AuditTest` launch `ResultActivity` using `startActivity()` or using `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: When `ResultActivity` is running, are there any other activities in the stack?

Comment: `AuditTest` calls `ResultActivity` by `startActivity()`. And when `ResultActivity` is running, there suppose to have no other activities in the stack, except the `ASyncTask` triggered by user's click on either of the buttons